# How to detect the match precision of OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: classification, nlp, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I've improved my text classification to topic module, from simple word2vec to piped tfidf and OneVsRestClassifier (using sklearn). It does improve the classification but with word2vec I was able to calculate the match percentage for each topic and with OneVsRestClassifier i get a match or no match to a specific topic. Is there a way to see with OneVsRestClassifier what was the percentage of the classification?

P.S.
I am not talking about evaluating the performance of the training but the actual real time matching percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.

Assuming that you have used sklearn's [OneVsRestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) and so you have a decision function for example a Support Vector Classifier with say linear kernel. Use `set_params` to change `probability` key to `True`, default is `False`. Use this in the OneVsRestClassifier classifier and then go with the inbuilt function `predict_proba` like

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
mod = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear').set_params(probability=True)).fit(samples,classes)
print mod.predict_proba(np.array([your_sample_vector]).reshape(1,-1))
```

**Edit:**

You can use your old `LinearSVC` with `decision_function` to find the distance from the hyperplane and convert them to probabilities like

```
mod = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()).fit(sample,clas)
proba = (1./(1.+np.exp(-mod.decision_function(np.array(your_test_array).reshape(1,-1)))))
proba /= proba.sum(axis=1).reshape((proba.shape[0], -1))\
print proba
```

Now you don't need tuning the parameters, I guess. :)

Comment: Thank you, it is strange that LinearSVC I used did not have this flexibility of setting probability as True.

Comment: Also it seems that SVC(kernel='linear') performs worse than LinearSVC with default params setup. I will have to fine tune the SVC to LinearSVC if I want to use the predict_proba method.

Comment: @MikeL See the edits.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a different question or not but the above probability calculation gives a spread match that always sums up to 100%, whereas I was hoping to get the actual probability of relation to a specific document (like a distance). For example if I have one document only i will get always 100% of a match because it is the only document in the game, even if the sentence is not relevant to the document.